# Value of nmap option

Tags: networking, security, nmap

I've found in some docs of port knocking, that it is used the option `--host-timeout` I don't understand why is 201 assigned to it? e.g.:

nmap -Pn --host-timeout 201 --max-retries 0 -p 7000 192.168.80.132

And what is the meaning of "201"?

I've read the nmap manpage, but still I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by quoting the relevant bit from the nmap documentation:

> `--host-timeout <time>` (Give up on slow target hosts)
>
> Some hosts simply take a long time to scan. This may be due to
>   poorly performing or unreliable networking hardware or software,
>   packet rate limiting, or a restrictive firewall. The slowest few
>   percent of the scanned hosts can eat up a majority of the scan
>   time. Sometimes it is best to cut your losses and skip those hosts
>   initially. Specify --host-timeout with the maximum amount of time
>   you are willing to wait. For example, specify 30m to ensure that
>   Nmap doesn't waste more than half an hour on a single host. Note
>   that Nmap may be scanning other hosts at the same time during that
>   half an hour, so it isn't a complete loss. A host that times out is
>   skipped. No port table, OS detection, or version detection results
>   are printed for that host.

This means that, if you call nmap with `--host-timeout 201`, then it
will try to get information for each scanned host for at most 201
seconds, and then, if the host still doesn't respond or if there's
still remaining information to get from this host, the scan will be
abandoned. As to the specific value 201, or three minutes and twenty
one seconds, it seems to be an arbitrary example value.